# Stop building when a missing module is encountered

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Is it possible to make PyInstaller stop execution when it fails to find a missing import in the files being compiled?  E. g. this source

```
import lalala
print("hellou")
```

Will be compiled just fine, and then fail in runtime.

The docs just say «make sure you have all packages available and in PYTHON_PATH when you build», but this is not helpful because one can accidentally forget to install something on a build server, and it is much less unpleasant to see a build error than to see a bug report

Comment: Are you sure? The [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#build-time-messages) specifies that _"an error message appears if Analysis detects an unconditional import and the module it names cannot be found"_ while _"a warning is given if the module named in an import cannot be found, but the import itself is conditional"_.

Comment: I want it to exit with an error code so that a build server can notify me of the failure, not produce a warning message no one ever reads